# Wordpress nav menu works for one site but not the other.

Tags: wordpress, menu, nav

I have followed the instructions on this document http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus
and it has worked for every subdomain website, for example fit.drttalks.ca but not the main website drttalks.ca

I have even gone so far as to copy the header.php and the functions.php files from fit.drttalks.ca, which is able to generate the nav menus to the files of the same name for drttalks.ca . But this still hasn't resulted in a solution.

I am very confused and have read through nearly all of the documentation and I have run several audits. I don't know if I may be missing a call function or if one document is just not working properly.

Comment: is theme location setting from `wp-admin/nav-menus.php` set correctly? If you've more than one theme location for menus then you might want to check that as well. Can't say much w/o any code.

Comment: I believe you mean this function, right?
<code>function register_nav_menus( $locations = array() ) {
 global $_wp_registered_nav_menus;

 add_theme_support( 'menus' );

 $_wp_registered_nav_menus = array_merge( (array) $_wp_registered_nav_menus, $locations );
}
</code>

Comment: I noticed this difference between the code of the nav-menus.php of the two websites. The one with the functioning nav-menu has this code.
<code>
$menu_items = 0 == $menu_id ? array() : (array) wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_id, array( 'post_status' => 'publish,draft' ) );

 $count = count( $menu_items );
</code>
Would that make much of a difference? Should I copy/paste it into the nav-menus.php doc for the other site?